# how to print a line when certain text pattern changes in bash?

Tags: bash, shell, unix, sh

I get below data from my ansible playbook when I want to check service status:

```
         host1  :  zookeeper       :  Active:  active  (running)  since  Wed  2023-02-15  13:57:02  HKT;  2  days   ago
         host2  :  zookeeper       :  Active:  active  (running)  since  Wed  2023-02-15  13:57:01  HKT;  2  days   ago
         host3  :  zookeeper       :  Active:  active  (running)  since  Wed  2023-02-15  13:57:01  HKT;  2  days   ago
         host1  :  Broker          :  Active:  active  (running)  since  Wed  2023-02-15  14:06:53  HKT;  1  day    23h  ago
         host2  :  Broker          :  Active:  active  (running)  since  Wed  2023-02-15  14:07:33  HKT;  1  day    23h  ago
         host3  :  Broker          :  Active:  active  (running)  since  Wed  2023-02-15  14:07:45  HKT;  1  day    23h  ago
         host4  :  Broker          :  Active:  active  (running)  since  Wed  2023-02-15  14:07:52  HKT;  1  day    23h  ago
         host2  :  SchemaRegistry  :  Active:  active  (running)  since  Wed  2023-02-15  14:13:41  HKT;  1  day    23h  ago
         host3  :  SchemaRegistry  :  Active:  active  (running)  since  Wed  2023-02-15  14:15:04  HKT;  1  day    23h  ago
         host4  :  Connect         :  Active:  active  (running)  since  Wed  2023-02-15  14:26:51  HKT;  1  day    23h  ago
         host1  :  ControlCenter   :  Active:  active  (running)  since  Wed  2023-02-15  13:45:09  HKT;  2  days   ago
         host5  :  KSQL            :  Active:  active  (running)  since  Wed  2023-02-15  14:20:28  HKT;  1  day    23h  ago
         host6  :  KSQL            :  Active:  active  (running)  since  Wed  2023-02-15  14:20:28  HKT;  1  day    23h  ago
         host5  :  RestProxy       :  Active:  active  (running)  since  Fri  2023-01-27  22:38:59  HKT;  2  weeks  6    days  ago
         host6  :  RestProxy       :  Active:  active  (running)  since  Wed  2023-02-15  14:31:59  HKT;  1  day    23h  ago
```

I then want to present this data in more readable format , so I want to print it as below

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
         host1  :  zookeeper       :  Active:  active  (running)  since  Wed  2023-02-15  13:57:02  HKT;  2  days   ago
         host2  :  zookeeper       :  Active:  active  (running)  since  Wed  2023-02-15  13:57:01  HKT;  2  days   ago
         host3  :  zookeeper       :  Active:  active  (running)  since  Wed  2023-02-15  13:57:01  HKT;  2  days   ago
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
         host1  :  Broker          :  Active:  active  (running)  since  Wed  2023-02-15  14:06:53  HKT;  1  day    23h  ago
         host2  :  Broker          :  Active:  active  (running)  since  Wed  2023-02-15  14:07:33  HKT;  1  day    23h  ago
         host3  :  Broker          :  Active:  active  (running)  since  Wed  2023-02-15  14:07:45  HKT;  1  day    23h  ago
         host4  :  Broker          :  Active:  active  (running)  since  Wed  2023-02-15  14:07:52  HKT;  1  day    23h  ago
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
         host2  :  SchemaRegistry  :  Active:  active  (running)  since  Wed  2023-02-15  14:13:41  HKT;  1  day    23h  ago
         host3  :  SchemaRegistry  :  Active:  active  (running)  since  Wed  2023-02-15  14:15:04  HKT;  1  day    23h  ago
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
         host4  :  Connect         :  Active:  active  (running)  since  Wed  2023-02-15  14:26:51  HKT;  1  day    23h  ago
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
         host1  :  ControlCenter   :  Active:  active  (running)  since  Wed  2023-02-15  13:45:09  HKT;  2  days   ago
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
         host5  :  KSQL            :  Active:  active  (running)  since  Wed  2023-02-15  14:20:28  HKT;  1  day    23h  ago
         host6  :  KSQL            :  Active:  active  (running)  since  Wed  2023-02-15  14:20:28  HKT;  1  day    23h  ago
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
         host5  :  RestProxy       :  Active:  active  (running)  since  Fri  2023-01-27  22:38:59  HKT;  2  weeks  6    days  ago
         host6  :  RestProxy       :  Active:  active  (running)  since  Wed  2023-02-15  14:31:59  HKT;  1  day    23h  ago
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I want to add a line after value in 2nd column changes. Could someone please help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this

```
awk -F: '{if($2!=p2){print "-------------------------";p2=$2} print}' file
```

#### edit

this code checks if the value of `$2` is different than `p2` then prints the separator and sets `p2` to the new value and prints the input line.

Comment: just perfect!!!. I added a manual line at very end as this doesnt print any line at the end as there is no change any more in $2

Comment: could you please explain this snippet of code? I am trying to do this where the first column is changing but unable to modify the code.

Comment: I got it now, delimiter was changed in my second use case
 awk -F" " '{if($1!=p1){print "-------------------------";p1=$1} print}' file